# Trying to get a load more button working on an Instagram Instafeed script but it isn't responding in my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, instafeedjs

I have an instagram feed integrated into a site I'm updating, I'm using instafeed.js which I have used before and I've set the feed up no problem but I'm trying to integrate a load more button which would load more images below the original set of images.

Even though I've done this before in another site and I'm using the exact same code as I did then, it doesn't want to make the load more button work. Can anyone help me find where I'm going wrong and get the solution?

HTML:

```
<div class="instagramFeed row">
    <div id="instafeed"></div>

    <p id="mybutton">Load More...</p>

</div>

</div> <!-- end container three -->
```

CSS:

```
.instagramFeed {
 padding-bottom: 40px;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted #666666;
}

#instafeed {
 position: relative;
 width: 108%;
 max-width: 108%;
 z-index: 999;
}

#instafeed img {
position: relative;
 width: 20%;
 max-width: 100%;
 margin-right: 4.5%;
 margin-top: 4.5%;
}

#mybutton {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 999;
}
```

JS:

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
target: 'instafeed',
get: 'tagged',
userId: 925022210,
tagName: 'justanotherinvegas',
accessToken: '925022210.467ede5.5d4dff89eb4c464392a859b27f8f43f5',
clientId: 'f1e17875a4214d059676570a91955844',
limit: '12',
sortBy: 'most-recent',
link: 'true',
template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
resolution: 'standard_resolution'
});

 // call feed.next() on button click
 $('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
  feed.next();
 });

 feed.run();
```

Comment: can you add a jsFiddle ?

Comment: Trying to but I have the script in my php page and then a script in a js folder so how would I put them both into a fiddle?

Comment: can you share the link for that page ?

Comment: I'm working in localhost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/unuLyzx0/2/) for the code provided, the problem is that `next()` is not defined.

Check the console.log where it shows that feed has `{options: Object, run: function, parse: function, _buildUrl: function}` there is no `next` function defined

I have updated my fiddle with an [older version](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/448aa4dd69d2924814419b5c449402fd74ec5cb1/instafeed.min.js) of the script that works. Apparently at some point, the script removed these features.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I also realised that I had the instafeed.js script without the pagination elements inside it so that was stopping it from loading more. Cheers

Comment: glad to help. Can you please mark the question as answered if your issue is solved :)