# Instafeed plugin Load More button is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, instafeedjs

I’m using instafeed js plugin and trying to use the load more button but it doesn’t work. I saw a post here with the same issue but i’m sorry is still not working for me. Any help?  thank you

Here is my code

```
         var feed = new Instafeed({
        get: 'user',
        userId: 300087,
        accessToken: '300087.467ede5.6af355f8b6c048b2bbfc6772ab918cf9',
        link: 'true',
        resolution: 'standard_resolution',
        limit: '20'
        });

        // call feed.next() on button click
         $('#load-more').on('click', function() {
         feed.next();
         });

        // run our feed!
         feed.run();
```

and in the html page

```
          <a id="load-more">load more</a>
```

Comment: Which post did you see?

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760591/trying-to-get-a-load-more-button-working-on-an-instagram-instafeed-script-but-it

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the 'after' segment to your feed variable

```
after: function() {
    if (!this.hasNext()) {
        moreButton.hide();
    }
}
```